# How do I prevent URL text being pasted into a WPF TextBox after a drag drop from a browser

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I have a WPF application which detects when a user has performed a drag drop operation from a web browser URL address line to a WPF TextBox. The problem I am having is that after I have captured the drop event the URL text from the browser is pasted into the WPF TextBox.

I don't want this to happen because when I have captured the event, I pull down the web page source into the WPF TextBox. After the text has been brought down WPF is then automatically pasting the URL from the browser URL Address into the TextBox where the mouse is currently positioned.

The result of this is I have the web page source in the TextBox then the page URL is pasted somewhere in the downloaded page content depending on where the mouse is positioned.

How can I prevent the URL text which was drag dropped from the browser from being pasted into the WPF TextBox after it has been dropped?

Below are the WPF events I am using:

```
   private void InfoTextBox_DragOver(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.Copy;
      else
        e.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.None;

      e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void InfoTextBox_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.Copy;
      else
        e.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.None;

      e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void InfoTextBox_PreviewDragOver(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
     e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void InfoTextBox_PreviewDrop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
      string[] filenames = (string[])e.Data.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop);

      if (filenames != null)
      { //This is a drag drop for a file from File Explorer
        InfoTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(filenames[0]);
      }
      else
      {
        string aUrl = (string)e.Data.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.StringFormat);
        if (aUrl != null)
        { //This is a drag drop for a URL from the browser
          WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
          Stream response = myClient.OpenRead(aUrl);

          // convert stream to string
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response);
          string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
          InfoTextBox.Text = text;

          response.Close();
        }
      }
    }
```

Below is the XAML for the InfoTexTBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="InfoTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
             Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="7" 
             DragEnter="InfoTextBox_DragEnter" 
             PreviewDrop="InfoTextBox_PreviewDrop"
             PreviewDragOver="InfoTextBox_PreviewDragOver"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,-8,80" BorderBrush="PowderBlue"
             BorderThickness="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" 
             Text="" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Handle the `DragDrop` event yourself (instead of `PreviewDrop`) so that the default handler is not called.

Comment: Thanks for the clue Ben. Setting the e.Handled property to true to indicate I am handling the event in the PreviewDrop event solves the problem.